# ImageResizer not longer working when TinyCache plugin is enabled

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I'm trying to get ImageResizer working with the TinyCache plugin. (i'll be on ImageResizer Essential Edition).

I am under Windows 10 / **IIS 10.0 with Integrated mode**

I have a .**net webform 4.7.2** website with the following **NuGet packages installed**:

- ImageResizer (v4.2.5)
- ImageResizer.Plugin.TinyCache (v4.2.5)
- ImageResizer.WebConfig (v4.2.5)

My **web.config** is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <!--<section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />-->
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection,ImageResizer"  requirePermission="false"  />
</configSections>
<!--check URL ~/resizer.debug.ashx-->
<resizer>
    <!--Unless you (a) use Integrated mode, or (b) map all requests to ASP.NET, 
        you'll need to add .ashx to your image URLs: image.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=20 

        Using IIS7 Integrated mode or the Visual Studio web server? You can skip this step. 
        You also don't need to do this if you are using the .jpg.ashx syntax.-->

    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true" />

    <plugins>
    <add name="TinyCache" />
    <!--<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/" physicalPath="..\Assets" vpp="false "/>-->
    <!--<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/" physicalPath="../Assets" vpp="false "/>-->
    </plugins>
</resizer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="YourErrorPage.aspx"
                mode="RemoteOnly">
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    </namespaces>
    <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
    <!-- This is for IIS7/8 Classic Mode and Cassini-->
    <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
    <!--This is for IIS7+ Integrated mode-->
    <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I disable the TinyCache plugin (simply comment the `<add name="TinyCache" />` line) it works when I try to call an image to resize (e.g. http:///Assets/TestImage.jpg?height=100 ; the image is resized ; here I have an TestImage.jpg picture in the Assets folder in the root directory of my website)

I however I get a warning on the diagnostic page http:///resizer.debug.ashx indicating I should enable cache:
`(Warning):    NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.`

So I enable the TinyCache plugin in web.config.

Then I get a warning on the diagnostic page http:///resizer.debug.ashx which I am unable to get rid off : `(Warning): To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.`

If I then try to resize a picture (e.g. http:///Assets/TestImage.jpg?height=100 .... or event (e.g. http:///Assets/TestImage.jpg.ashx?height=100 which I should not need in my case with Win10 - IIS 10 Integrated mode) I get the following error :
[image: error when calling http://<myServer>/Assets/Porte.jpg?height=100]

Note : the english version of this error (I'm in French) would be

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Worth noted, the file /App_Data/tiny_cache.cache is never created ! (I have however granted all privileges on this folder to the user running the IIS Pool.... as well as all users on my DEV box !)

If you have any idea/solution, many thanks in advance !

I'm considering using https://imageprocessor.org/ instead of ImageResizer as didn't come with any pain :)

Comment: Could you attach the picture or copy/paste the error you encountered? It didn't come through.

Comment: ouch sorry, the pic didn't come through your right. I've edited the post 

Comment: Did you try installing the protobuf-net dependency? https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [protobuf-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) nuget package. Because the dll is missing, a FileNotFound exception is thrown, which in turn is converted to a 404 error.